# How to optimize jqGrid event handling

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

My jqgrid intensively use a `CustomFormatter` to create hyperlink cell content.

The FormatFunction looks like this:

```
function formatLink(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    var res = cellValue.split(" - ");
    var filter = options['pos'] + "@" + rowObject['Filter'] + "@Compiled";
    return '<a href="#" OnClick="SearchEvaluations(' + '\'' + filter + '\'' + ')">' + res[0] + '</a> - ' + res[1];
}
```

When the grid show a lot of rows, I suppose that the time spent in run the function could and should be optimized.

I think that I can attach a click handler with a jQuery delegate to all the `<a>` tags inside the grid.

```
$('#grid').delegate('a', 'click', function (
```

At thi point, how can I access data inside the row clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method onSelectRow in jqgrid. I had a requirement to open a jsp based on the data of the clicked jQgrid row. My code looks like below:

```
onSelectRow : function(rowid, status, e) {
        var selRow = $(this).getGridParam("selrow");
        var selReferralId = $(this).getCell(selRow, 'referralId'); 
        $("#referralDetailsTab").load(contextRoot+"refDetailsTab?refId=" + selReferralId );
```